# Improvement deque movement from O(n) to O(1)

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, deque

The task is there are N numbers in a queue.
And the origin sequence is from 1 to N.
The operation “Move a b” means to move all numbers in front of a (including a) 
and then insert them in front of b(without changing order)
and output the whole queue when "Exit" appear.

Here is my code to deal with the "Move":

```
//I establish q & q1 deque

while(cin>>commend){
    if(commend == "Move"){
         cin>>a>>b;
         int checka,checkb = 0;

            //search for a,b position
            //it1,it2 are both iterators

            for(int m = 0; m < num ; m++){
                if(q[m] == a){
                    it1 = q.begin()+m;
                    checka = 1;
                }
                else if(q[m] == b){
                    it2 = q.begin()+m;
                    con2 = m; //store m in con2 to use below
                    checkb = 1;
                }
                else if( checka == 1 && checkb == 1)
                    break;
            }

            //con is also a iterator
            //q1 is a new deque to store the elements before (include)number"a" 
            //procedures below are moving the numbers before(include)"a" and push_front the elements between number "a" and number "b"

            for(con = it1; con>= q.begin() ; con--)
                q1.push_front(*con);
            for(con = it2; con > it1+1; con--){
                q1.push_front(*con);

            }

            //copy the "swaped" elements from q1 to q
            //and clear q1

            for(int m = 0; m<con2-1; m++)
                q[m] = q1[m];
            q1.clear();
    }
}
```

But the speed is O(N) and i don't know where i can improve this if it is required to complete the task with O(1).

Any suggestion except building a linked-list ?

Comment: if you know where in the list that your "cut point" is, then a queue re-arranging can be O(1). but if you have to scan that list to find your cut-point, then there's no way it can be O(1).

Comment: I don't see how this can be done in `O(1)`. You are doing an `O(1)` operation `n` times, which will always result in an `O(n)` runtime

Comment: This is a programming competition question right? I'm sure I've seen other answers to this question, but I can't find them because I've forgotten what the problem is called. Can you include the details of where the problem is from so this question can be linked to the others? Specifically, I'm sure there was a good answer to this question which involved some variant of a skip list.

Comment: @PaulHankin actually this question is given by my teacher to train my programming skill, so i want to complete the o(1)task. by the way i have completed it with Linked list .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maintain a linked list of your numbers in the queue plus an index (a hash, like std::unordered_map) with each number as a key pointing to the number in the queue. To change the order, you simply look up a and b in the index in O(1) time, go to the numbers in the List and swap their linking pointers to change their order, again in O(1) time.

Comment: so linked list would be the best performance way to deal with it?

Comment: This is the simplest answer which I can think of. Depending on your exact requirements, there would be more efficient ways to do this but this solution is O(1) which answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do the `Move` function in `O(1)`. This is because the complexity is determined by both the search and the create operations. Your search operation takes `O(n)`, and you cannot reduce it unless and until you change the data structure(which you won't want to do). Even if you, hypothetically do you search in `O(1)`, you will only be able to do the copy operation in `O(1)` if the data is stored in a continuous block of memory, and then you can use `memcpy()`. However, your search operation will never go under `O(n)`, and hence there is, according to me, no scope for changing the asymptotic bounds. Also, your program won't do anything if `a` and `b` are equal.

Comment: Because of the operations' limit ,Is it the only way i need to change the data structure to improve the efficiency ?

Comment: @WayneWilliams Well I guess it's possible only if you hash the iterators, like which number is present at which position. Hash them, and you would get position in `O(1)`. Then use a deque which stores elements in a contiguous memory block, and use `memcpy()`. That would be the only solution I can think of.